# How to create a custom formatter with go 1.13 error?

Tags: go, error-handling

With go 1.13, we can now wrap our error this way, `fmt.Errorf("... %w ...", ..., err, ...)` (https://golang.org/pkg/errors).

While this is great, there seems to be no way to create a custom formatter. Let say I want to have different spaces depending on the depth of the error, I'll get all of the errors in the tree if I just get the string representation of the error, `err.Error()`.

Please see below for an example.

I've tried using `fmt.Sprintf` with `%s` and `%v` verbs, get the string representation from `Error()`, and `fmt.Sprint`.

```golang
// sprintError prints err in top-down order
func sprintError(err error) string {
    var stack []string
    level := 0
    spacesPerLevel := 2

    for err != nil {
        space := strings.Repeat(" ", level*spacesPerLevel)
        msg := fmt.Sprintf("%s%s", space, err)
        stack = append(stack, msg)
        err = errors.Unwrap(err)
        level++
    }

    msg := strings.Join(stack, "\n")
    return msg
}
```

Example:

```golang
err := fmt.Errorf("level 1")
err = fmt.Errorf("level 2: %w", err)
fmt.Print(sprintError(err))
```

Output:

```
level 2: level 1
  level 1
```

Expected:

```
level 2:
  level 1
```

Answer (score 0):

> [T]here seems to be no way to create a custom formatter

Exactly. That part of the original proposal did not make it into Go 1.13.
So you cannot do what you would like to do, at least not in an easy way.
You could try and strip of the unwrapped error string from the original
but this relies on string manipulation.

Comment: I guess you're referring to this one right, https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/xerrors#Formatter? If this is the case, what's your current approach rather than doing it in a hacky way, striping the unwrapped error string from the original. Should I just use xerrors then?

Comment: @LukasHerman I do not have any approach as we do not see the need for a fancy custom formatting of our errors: We decorate them where needed only and they read fine.